# match a string in two columns then print count AWK

Tags: awk, csv

I have a csv file that contains 21 columns. I want to search a string in two columns then count the total number of occurrences.

sample of my dataset

```
columnA     columnB    columnC  columnD
abc          Apple      Apple     today
nbd          apple      NULL      tomorrow
ccc          apple      Apple     today
```

I was able to search the string in the file. But I want to search for the string in two columns only. My search is case sensitive(exact match)

```
awk -F',' '/Apple/ {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv
```

I would like to apply the search on columnB and columnC ($2 && $3). 
The output should be 3

Any tip would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: your example input file isn't comma-separated.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /^Apple$/ {++count} $3 ~ /^Apple$/ {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv
```

or, since you want an exact match, `==` will do instead of `~`:

```
awk -F',' '$2 == "Apple" {++count} $3 == "Apple" {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv
```

This will increment `count` if it is found in **either** `$2` or `$3`.

If you want to increment `count` only if it is found in both, use:

```
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /^Apple$/ && $3 ~ /^Apple$/ {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv

awk -F',' '$2 == "Apple" && $3 == "Apple" {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv
```

or (concatenating both the fields to match AND the string x 2):

```
awk -F',' '$2$3 ~ /^AppleApple$/ {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv

awk -F',' '$2$3 == "AppleApple" {++count} END{print count}' Dataset.csv
```

Comment: Thank you cas for your reply. 

Using `==` with `&&` or with `||` returns no output . 
and using `~` with `||` returns an output but I wonder if it is the count of both columns.  
I would like an exact match as I mentioned. 
My original dataset contains around 500,000 rows, so it's hard to verify.

Comment: i did test all of these before i posted them.  As I mentioned in a comment, the data you posted is NOT comma-separated, if your actual data is the same then that will be the cause.  Either change the data to be comma-separated or get rid of the `-F','`.

Comment: Shouldn't that data be comma separated because it is in a csv file? I hope I am correct. Thank you,

Comment: the filename is irrelevant.  the contents of the file dictate what kind of file it is.  the sample you posted was **not** comma-separated. It was space or tab separated.   I had to modify it to replace the field separators with commas so the above awk commands would work.

Comment: the || example would only count the first match on each line, not both.  $2 and $3 have to be tested for separately, not combined with and OR.  fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk with field separator set to the search pattern:

```
awk -F'Apple' '{count+=NF-1}END{print count}' file
```

The `count` variable is increment with the number of fields and printed at the end of the file.

---

An alternative using GNU awk, needed to use RS as a regex (word boundary, thanks to @cas):

```
 awk -v RS='\\<Apple\\>' 'END{print NR-1}' file
```

This simply checks how many record `NR` where found in the file.

Comment: +1, nice. maybe `-F` should have word boundary anchors `awk -F'\\<Apple\\>'`, so it doesn't match Apples or ApplePie etc.

Comment: @cas thanks for this comment. Note however that it won't work in `--posix` mode.